# JQuery Mobile - Disable "enter" / script to not allow using enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, jquery-mobile

In textarea JQM, How to disable "enter" or not allow using enter? Is it possible to do?

`<textarea maxlength='200' name="comment" id="comment" data-mini="true" data-theme="a" cols="40" rows="3" ></textarea`>

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this :

```
   $("#comment").on("keypress", function (e) {
     if (e.which === 13) {
       e.preventDefault();
       //alert("Keypress averted");
     }
   });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/JTwXv/

Comment: try $('#comment') to limit the handler to just that text box. Also, the default submit action and other actions happen on keypress, so try `$('comment').on('keypress, ...`

Comment: I've tried it. But when I input some text and click enter the value will null b.coz this code `this.value = "";` I want when I input some text and I enter it. the value will not change. How to do it? ><